# Trouble Installing and Importing SendKeys -- Update

Tags: python, visual-studio, sendkeys

I am trying to install SendKeys for Python.

If I use

```
pip install SendKeys
```

I get a link error:

```
 _sendkeys.c(150): warning C4013: 'Py_InitModule' undefined; assuming extern returning int 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED, \10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit__sendkeys
build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\_sendkeys.cp35-win_amd64.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

If I download the 64-bit .whl and try to install it with pip locally I get:

```
sendkeys-0.3-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I get the same error if I try the 32-bit version.

pip is up to date. Is there something wrong with my Visual Studio setup?

--Update--

I was able to intall SendKeys after updating the Python module in Visual Studio, but I get the following error when I try to import SendKeys

```
>>> import SendKeys
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sendkeys-0.3-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\SendKeys.py", line 419
    except (ValueError,AssertionError),e:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code that throws the error is in main:

```
def main(args=None):
 import getopt

 if args is None:
    args = sys.argv[1:]

 try:
    opts,args = getopt.getopt(args, 
        "hp:d:f:", ["help","pause","delay","file"])
 except getopt.GetoptError:
    usage()

 pause=0
 delay=0
 filename=None

 for o, a in opts:
    if o in ('-h','--help'):
        usage()
    elif o in ('-f','--file'):
        filename = a
    elif o in ('-p','--pause'):
        try:
            pause = float(a)
            assert pause >= 0
        except (ValueError,AssertionError),e:
            error('`pause` must be >= 0.0')
    elif o in ('-d','--delay'):
        try:
            delay = float(a)
            assert delay >= 0
        except (ValueError,AssertionError),e:
            error('`delay` must be >= 0.0')

 time.sleep(delay)
                                  ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation error was caused by missing components of Visual Studio, and was fixed by updating the Python Tools for Visual Studio. That's probably a common problem for installation and updates on Windows.

I still have not fixed the import issue. I think it has to do with the python version, but I'm not sure. In any event, I've chosen to use pyautogui instead, so the issue is moot.

Answer (score 0):

Download .zip file, unzip and do `python setup.py install`

Comment: That gives me the same link error as using pip, but it referenced different directories.