# Python SendKeys Installation Error Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, sendkeys

I am a newbie to Python. I am using SendKeys Module in Python to perform the SendKeys Operation. when I try to execute the code, I get the below error. I landed up  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411145/trouble-installing-and-importing-sendkeys-update/53568212) but still didn't resolve. can someone pls give me a detailed help on this, please?

**Notes:**
- using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition with Python 3.6 x32

**Eror:**
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_86\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts__startup__.py", line 14, in run

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_86\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run

File "C:\VisualStudioProjects\PythonLearning\SiebelIncrementalCompile\Published\Src\SiebelIncrementalCompile.py", line 12, in

File "D:\SiebelIncrementalCompile\lib\SendKeys.py", line 419
    except (ValueError,AssertionError),e:
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you paste in the code that triggers this?

Comment: even when invoking Sendkeys("abc",1) the above error is popping up

Comment: A minor correction. Even when i do import SendKeys i get the error. below is the info... 

C:\Python36_86>python.exe

Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7 ) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

>>> import SendKeys
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\site-packages\sendkeys-0.3-py3.6-win32.egg\SendKeys.py", line 419
    except (ValueError,AssertionError),e:
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax